# Blank text editor in Vis Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, text, editor

I have just installed VS 2005.  I created a project.  I added code to the project and then debugged the code.  The program ran ok.  I save the project.  Everything saves fine.  I go to open the project and the text editor is blank, or so it appears.  After further investigation I notice that the code is there but I just can't see it.  I debug and the program runs but no code can be seen.  Strange.  What is additonally weird, is I have installed the python idle and it to is blank, no code to be seen.  However, the code is in there because I can run the code. I have adjusted just about every display property in VS as well as the os display props.  I am using a Dell Latitude M60 Laptop, w/ windows xp professional, sp2, intel pentium M, 2 Ghz, 1gb ram.  What do you think?  Any body have this happen to them?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be.. Right_Mouse+Click on the file in the Solution Explorer and chose "View Code"?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes windows needs a restart :-)

Comment: Whenever I've had a problem with text display in the Visual Studio IDE (such as forgetting fonts/colours), restarting Windows cleared it right up.